# Why in this program size of integer is 8?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

```
// pointer of array

#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 3, 5, 6, 7, 9 };
    int *p = arr;
    int (*ptr)[5] = &arr;

    printf("p = %p, ptr = %p\n", p, ptr);

    printf("*p = %d, *ptr = %p\n", *p, *ptr);

    printf("sizeof(p) = %lu, sizeof(*p) = %lu\n",
                          sizeof(p), sizeof(*p));

    printf("sizeof(ptr) = %lu, sizeof(*ptr) = %lu\n",
                        sizeof(ptr), sizeof(*ptr));

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
p = 0x7ffde1ee5010, ptr = 0x7ffde1ee5010
*p = 3, *ptr = 0x7ffde1ee5010
sizeof(p) = 8, sizeof(*p) = 4
sizeof(ptr) = 8, sizeof(*ptr) = 20
```

Here why `sizeof(p)` or `sizeof(ptr)` is **8**?

This code is an example of pointer to array

Why 8 and why not 4 ?

Comment: Please remember that both `p` and `ptr` are *pointers*. And on 64-bit systems pointers are typically 8 bytes (64 bits).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude then why *ptr = 20

Comment: Because `ptr` is pointing to an array of five 4-byte `int` elements. That means `*ptr` is the array itself, with the size of `5 * sizeof(int)` (i.e. `5 * 4`) bytes. `ptr` is a pointer, `*ptr` is the object that `ptr` is pointing to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a 64-bit system, which yours evidently is, pointers are represented by 8 bytes, regardless of what they point *to*.

In your example, both `p` and `ptr` are pointers. In the case of `p`, we have a pointer to the first `int` in the array. On your system evidently `int` is 4 bytes. In the case of `ptr`, it's been declared as a pointer to an array of 5 `int` values, which is 20 bytes.